# AngularJS $.map: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

`Function.map` throwing console error while performing `$.map` function. where `result.extraIds` includes 300k records.

```
$scope.extraIds = $.map(result.extraIds, function (item) {
     return item.id;
});
```

This error internally stopping other functionality.

How can I handle this scenario?

Comment: Can you add sample data here? Or create a fiddle?

Comment: I create an array of 500000 elements and extracted `id`  from it using `Array.map` and it's working fine. [FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/n6wtxoza/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got resolved by using JavaScript [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function instead of jQuery map.

```
$scope.extraIds = result.extraIds.map(function (item) {
    return item.id;
});
```